# Computing $\int_C \frac{8e^{iz}}{ z^2+i} dz,$ where $C = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 3\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

If $C = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 3\}$, how would one compute $$\int_C \frac{8e^{iz}}{ z^2+i} dz$$
without using the residue theorem. It is obvious that the function is analytic so can we apply the Cauchy Integral Formula?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

i) The poles inside the contour are

> $$z=\sqrt{i},-\sqrt{i}$$

ii) use partial fraction to write

> $$ \frac{1}{z^2+i}=\frac{A}{z+\sqrt{i}}+\frac{B}{z-\sqrt{i}}$$

iii) apply Cauchy Formula

> $$ f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_\gamma \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\, dz.  $$