# Contour integrals

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $\int_C\dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{z^2-1}$ where

a) $C$ is the clockwise oriented circle $\left|z \right| = 2$;

b) $C$ is the anti-clockwise oriented square with sides on $x= \pm2$  and $y= \pm2$;

c) $C$ is the clockwise oriented circle $\left|z-1 \right|= 1$.

So for this I would set $z = x+iy$ and separate the function into a real and imaginary part to solve the integral, right? And how do i know what bunds to put on the integral?

Comment: You would use Cauchy's theorem. Do you know how to do a contour integral? Is this homework?

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572864/computing-int-c-frac8eiz-z2i-dz-where-c-z-in-mathbbc-z/572869#572869).

Comment: Review for an exam @BrunoJoyal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{1}{z^2-1}=\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+1)}$$
Hence, the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2-1}$ has simple poles at $z=\pm 1$. We get
$$\mathrm{res}_{z=1}f=\frac{1}{2},\quad\mathrm{res}_{z=-1}f=-\frac{1}{2}$$
For (a) the given contour encloses both poles so you have
$$\int_{\gamma_a} \frac{1}{z^2-1}dz = -2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-1}{2}\right)=0$$
For (b) the contour is reversed, but also encloses both poles, so
$$\int_{\gamma_b} \frac{1}{z^2-1}dz = 2\pi i\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{-1}{2}\right)=0$$
For (c) the contour encloses only the pole $z=1$, so
$$\int_{\gamma_c} \frac{1}{z^2-1}dz = -2\pi i\cdot\frac{1}{2}=-\pi i$$

Comment: so if the given contour encloses both poles, its always $0$? I have a similar example, $\int_C\!\frac{2z+1}{z^4-2z^2+1}dz$ circle |$z$| = $10$ clockwise... there are poles at $\pm1$ , so the contour encloses both poles, so its $0$ in this case too???