# contour integrals complex analysis 2

Tags: complex-analysis

Evaluate $\int_C\!\frac{2z-1}{z^4-2z^2+1}dz$ where $C$ is the circle |$z$|=$10$ oriented clockwise.

I have a exam tomorrow and need to understand this, can someone please help.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572864/computing-int-c-frac8eiz-z2i-dz-where-c-z-in-mathbbc-z/572869#572869). You need to factor the denomonator to find thr poles that lie inside the contour.

Comment: @Danathon If you search around the side you'll find lots and lots of examples of these kind of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the residue theorem. Look for the poles (in this case zeros of the denominator) inside $|z|=10$. Hint: the denominator factors into $(z^2 - 1)^2$, so the poles are $\pm 1$ each with multiplicity 2.

Comment: the $res_{z=1}$ is $\frac{2z-1}{2i}$?

Comment: The residue should be a number -- looks like you need to sub in for z.